# Problem with Marshalling char* in c#

Tags: c#, dll, marshalling

I have a problem calling this function from a c++ DLL in c#

```
INT32 WINAPI PM_COM_GetText(INT32 TextId, char* pBuf, INT32 BufSize);
```

It writes a Text in a buffer for a given text id.
I try to call it with the following c# code, but I constantly get an access violation and don't undrestand why:

```
public string GetText(Int32 TextId)
{
  Int32 BufSize = 256;
  StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder(BufSize);
  PM_COM_GetText(TextId, Str, BufSize);
  return Str.ToString();
}

[DllImport("ComDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern Int32 PM_COM_GetText(Int32 TextId, StringBuilder Str, Int32 BufSize);
```

I don't see what's wrong, it looks to me like many other code snippets I found in the web.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your C# code.  Make sure this method isn't an instance method of a C++ class, that's all I can guess at.  You'll probably have to debug the unmanaged code.

Comment: Calling the DLL function from an unmanaged C++ program works. And no its not an instance method of a class, it's a plain function.

Comment: Then u r missing some information here. Need more details about what you are trying to do. Code will be helpful.

Comment: The C# code is ok. The problem was the underlying DLL, I forgot to call an initialization function. Debugging is always a good idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `StringBuilder Str` in the DllImport declaration looks strange to me. I'd suggest trying to make it a plain ol' `string`.

Comment: that doesn't work because the DLL parmeter is an output parameter. As far as I know string only works for input parameters (and there it works fine). By the way I've tried this aleady but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Yep, string builder looks strange. Maybe char[]???
You should also check if actually those are not uints.

These kind if things (using int when you should use uint, lets say) will have no problem in C++ but will throw an exception in .net 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `out StringBuilder Str` or `out string Str`

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `StringBuilder` parameter a `byte[]` and use

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yourstring")
```